# Java JDBC Postgres: Select with single quote

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I've been testing the code over and over found that the issue is the single quote. As you can see in the query below, I used the single quote in the where clause. If I remove that I get a result but if I put it back even though the are rows that satisfies the filter it does not return anything. I also tried to use a view on this. Putting the where clause in the view and selecting the view directly and not using any filter. Still it does not return anything.

```
  try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://{ipaddress}/database?user=postgres&password=password");

    Statement Stmt = Conn.createStatement();
    String sqlCommand = "SELECT col1_timestamp , col2 FROM table WHERE col1_timestamp > '00:01:00' ";

    ResultSet RS = Stmt.executeQuery(sqlCommand);

    while (RS.next()) {
        data.add(RS.getInt("col1_timestamp ")
                + "=>" + RS.getString("col2"));
    }
    // Clean up after ourselves
    RS.close();
    Stmt.close();
    Conn.close();
}
catch (SQLException E) {
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + E.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState:     " + E.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError:  " + E.getErrorCode());
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

I also already tried:

```
  String sqlCommand = "SELECT col1_timestamp, col2 FROM table "
                + " WHERE col2= ? AND (now() - col1_timestamp::timestamp with time zone) < interval ? ";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = Conn.prepareStatement(sqlCommand);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "test");
        preparedStatement.setTime(2, new Time(new Long(-28680000))); //String(2, "00:02:00");
```

Still does not work, instead it throws an error on the second parameter.

It's pretty simple task really but it always returns a blank value.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The interval literals are quite limited (in SQL in general and in Postgres) and you can't use a parameter for the unit of the interval literal

If you always have the same unit (e.g. minutes) you can do something like this:

```
String sqlCommand =
   "SELECT col1_timestamp, col2 FROM table " + 
   " WHERE col2= ? " + 
   " AND (now() - col1_timestamp::timestamp with time zone) < interval '1' minute * ?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = Conn.prepareStatement(sqlCommand);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "test");
preparedStatement.setInt(2, 5); // five minutes
```

If you need to query for different units (hours, minutes, days) then you either need to use the approriate number of minutes for each of them or change the SQL each time: `interval '1' day * ?` or `interval '1' hour * ?`

Comment: is a single quote a concern at all? When I also tried to use a view it comes out wrong.

Comment: Tried it and it throws an error on the second parameter saying ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"

Comment: @oneofakind: not sure what you mean with the single quotes problem. The code as I have shown works for me, there must be something you are not telling us. Also your error message also doesn't seem to match the code. There is no $2 in my example

Comment: I'm sorry I did not scroll right. Tried it still returns nothing. Keep in mind that I keep on trying this on my pgAdmin and it does return rows. Printed out preparedStatement.toString(); to see the final query. I do not know what else to tell you.

Comment: @oneofakind Update your Question to show the exact text you used in pgAdmin. Also specific your version of Postgres.

Comment: re: 'syntax error at or near "$2"' - I suspect that @oneofakind was trying to use `... INTERVAL ?` which, as you said, does not work. Your approach *does* work, for me anyway. (I tested it because I thought that `interval '1' minute * ?` might be a typo that should have been `interval '1 minute' * ?` but in fact both formats work.)

Comment: @GordThompson: `interval '1' minute` is the standard (ANSI) SQL format for an interval literal. `interval '1 minute'` is a Postgres specific format.

Comment: @GordThompson Yep your right I did do that. @ a_horse_with_no_name But yeah your query works fine if I ran it in PgAdmin but does not return anything if I ran it in the code. If it it's okay to both of you this must be it but for some reason it does not to me. It must be the version I'm using? maybe?

Comment: @oneofakind Did you see my comment to your other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261866/jdbc-postgresql-unable-to-retrieve-records#comment43010458_27261866)? Yes, there may well be something about your particular Java/JDBC configuration that is causing problems. We just need more help from you to determine what that might be.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will try that. I just thought I'd open a new thread because its a new problem. Thanks!